# I need to track updates in a table I merge from a view

Tags: oracle

To track changes in my tables, I use a lookup table merge lookup. Here I try to store the highest `ORA_ROWSCN` value from my merged tables in an attempt to identify the changes.I am using the below query but i get the following error.

**Query:**

```
UPDATE MERGE_LOOKUP SET
MAX_ROWSCN = ( SELECT MAX(ORA_ROWSCN) 
               FROM INVCONTROL_MER) 
WHERE TABLENAME = 'INVCONTROL_MER';
```

**Error:**

```
ORA01747 : INVALID USER.TABLE.COLUMN, TABLE.COLUMN, OR COLUMN SPECIFICATION.
```

Please suggest a solution where i can get this MAX(ORA_ROWSCN)?

Comment: Is this mysql or oracle?

Comment: @BobC specific to oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have some syntax errors:

```
UPDATE MERGE_LOOKUP SET
MAX_ROWSCN = ( SELECT MAX(ORA_ROWSCN) 
               FROM INVCONTROL_MER 
               WHERE TABLENAME = 'INVCONTROL_MER'
             )
```

Now this also assumes that you have a column called `TABLENAME` in your table `INVCONTROL_MER`

Perhaps you just want this:

```
UPDATE MERGE_LOOKUP SET
MAX_ROWSCN = ( SELECT MAX(ORA_ROWSCN) 
               FROM INVCONTROL_MER 
             )
```

Comment: The table MERGE_LOOKUP is used for tracking tables. "tablename" is a column.

Comment: Ok, so did my first answer work? If not, what is the error?

Comment: Error: ORA01747 : INVALID USER.TABLE.COLUMN, TABLE.COLUMN, OR COLUMN SPECIFICATION.

Comment: Can you describe the two tables